# UDeploy automate resource mapping for agents

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, urbancode, udeploy

I'm trying to automate the Resource mapping for agents in IBM uDeploy. I have a continuous delivery pipeline using Jenkins, Udeploy and Private Cloud.

I'm thinking of a shell/python script which will invoke uDeploy CLI and add the agent to a predefined group in resource tree and add certain components to the agent. The agent name, resource group and component names can predefined in the script.

Here is my resource tree

```
- INSANE-CI
    * APPS
    * SANDBOX
    * PROTOTYPE
```

I'm struggling to find documentation about the CLI calls to add an agent to resource group and then add components.

I was wondering has anyone tried to implement this or has anyone any idea how I should approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use resource templates to accomplish this. Part of the template is an agent prototype. You map component resources to the agent prototype. Once the actual agent is alive, it gets automatically added to the resource tree. You'd need some naming convention for the agent to make it work properly. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.5/com.ibm.udeploy.doc/topics/resources_templates.html

The cli call should be createResource, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.5/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_createresource.html